# How to enable location directly from yes button

Tags: java, android

I am working on creating an Android app and I am facing a problem while enabling location directly from my app. On the first launch, when location permission is allowed, the app works correctly, but when it is reopened, the app crashes.

Here is the source code for my app:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    settingsrequest();
}

private void settingsrequest() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
 // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}


public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if(mCurrLocationMarker != null){
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOption.position(latLng);
    markerOption.title("Current Position");
    markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResult){
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

            if(grantResult.length > 0
                    && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(mGoogleApiClient == null){
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permisison denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Posting the trace from user:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gprs,       PID: 31433
          java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
        at     com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at     com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown    Source)
        at       com.gprs.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:185)
        at        com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.zzm(Unknown Source)
        at    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzk(Unknown Source)
        at    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzsb(Unknown Source)
        at    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zztp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.gprs, PID: 31433
                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please post it in the question.

Comment: i have done the edit please check it

Answer (score 0):

As per your stack trace Google API client is not connected or not able to connect.

So when the setting result is received, check whether the GoogleAPI client is connected or not.

```
 case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    startLocationUpdates();
                  }else{
                        Log.e(TAG,"Error in connecting Google API client");
                       }
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                    break;
            }
            break;
```

Comment: again app is  crashed

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkpermission (){if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        REQUEST_LOCATION);
} else {
  Location myLocation =
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}}
```

then.....

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        if(grantResults.length == 1
           && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We can now safely use the API we requested access to
            Location myLocation =
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        } else {
            // Permission was denied or request was cancelled
        }
    }
}
```

you can see full here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
public static void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity, int accuracy) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(accuracy);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    activity, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Also mGoogleApiClient should be connected before hitting this method.

Comment: when method is called in on create which parameter is passed

Comment: which parameters are use for passing in method.

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java   you have to connect to googleAPI client in ur activity

Comment: i am not getting this method in this given link..(source code)

Comment: the given link is to create ur client and whenever u want user to get the user to enable location on one click call the method I provided previously